# how does a network response reach a pod in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, networking, routes, azure-aks

I am wondering how network traffic reaches a pod in AKS.

Let's say I have a simple pod that isn't exposed via load balancer or ingress. If I do a web request to the public web with something like curl https://google.com then I also get a response. How can the response find its way to the pod if it doesn't have a public IP?

Somewhere must be a gateway or something of that sort. I assume. I am interested in finding its public IP address for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: It's all about implementation of the cloud is used. E.g. Azure AKS [virtual netwoks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network#kubernetes-basics) are created (a bit different implementation of both CNIs). Same goes to [virtual networks itself](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview). There are most likely several endpoints like loadbalancers which are exposed to the internet from Azure network like [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet?tabs=stv2#control-plane-ip-addresses)

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kube-proxy` is running on each node and facilitates traffic, both east-west and north-south, for the other pods on the node. The particulars will depend on the implementations of the Azure network you've designed, but the traffic will go out to a NAT gateway or, if the node is in public address space, straight out from there.

You could get the public IP by using one of the many "curl my IP" services out there.